# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied : 'C:\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\QtCore.pyd'

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I have tried to install from this web site : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/

I didn't get any error initially. Then I want to create a window, I used 'QtWidget' and get [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4YYY.png)

I have tried to install PyQt5 using --< pip install PyQt5

I get this error : ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:'C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `--user` option when installing? `pip install --user PyQt5`

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it wasn't worked

Comment: Try installing without `--user` through an elevated terminal (admin command prompt)

Answer (score 0):

pip install PyQt5n --user , this should work.

Comment: `PyQt5n` is a typo for the package name and in the comments, the questioner indicates that they have already tried the `--user` argument without success.